# SQL Sub Query with column prefix

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a large Stored Procedure and there is a subquery within it that looks like the following.

```
SELECT COUNT(userID) AS totalLikes FROM apsLikes WHERE likeID = 'empowerment_'+A.[submissionID]
FOR    XML PATH ('likes'), TYPE, ELEMENTS
```

Within the column `likeID` i have values with a `prefix_id`

When I try and run the query I get this error:

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'empowerment_' to data type int.
```

The data type of likeID is varchar(60) so not sure what it means?

Comment: it's treating this as a character plus an integer : 'empowerment_'+A.[submissionID] I'm assuming submissionID is an integer, and empowerment_ + any integer will be an error as it tries to convert 'empowerment' to an integer. convert submissionID to a varchar, then add them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do an explicit `cast()`:

```
SELECT COUNT(userID) AS totalLikes
FROM apsLikes
WHERE likeID = 'empowerment_' + cast(A.[submissionID] as varchar(255))
FOR    XML PATH ('likes'), TYPE, ELEMENTS;
```

The problem is that `+` can mean either addition or string concatenation.  Because the second argument is an integer, it assumes the `+` is addition, and `'empowerment_'` cannot be converted to an integer.  Hence, the error.

Answer (score 0):

SubmissionID is probably of the data typeint. Try this.

```
SELECT COUNT(userID) AS totalLikes 
FROM apsLikes WHERE likeID = 'empowerment_'+ CAST(A.[submissionID] AS NVARCHAR(255))
FOR    XML PATH ('likes'), TYPE, ELEMENTS
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that SQL Server interprets the plus sign as an addition operator rather than a concatenation operator.  Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(userID) AS totalLikes 
FROM apsLikes WHERE likeID = 'empowerment_'+ CAST(A.[submissionID] AS VARCHAR(50))
FOR XML PATH ('likes'), TYPE, ELEMENTS
```